# Jaggedness in my rendered image in cycles rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

Why there are so many jagged edges in my renders?
[image]

Here is the part file link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/mexg8QWK

Comment: Have you shade smoothed? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hello :). Looks like antialiasing artifacts - is the render displayed in 1:1 size?

Comment: @JachymMichal yes I have displayed this in 1:1 size only. I will add blend file. May be that can give you some insight

Comment: @moonboots Yes it is. I have also kept Auto smooth in my quick favorites :D Sure, I am sharing the file in a moment.

Comment: weird, it works fine here...

Comment: @moonboots in the blend file I shared, my setting will remain as it is or it will take your settings for rendering? It has got into my mind so much that I have started to see it in my viewport too lol

Comment: here it's good both in viewport and rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are antialiasing artifacts caused by low resolution and high contrast.
Renders in 4K/8K (or with lower contrast) are visibly less jagged.

**Why:**
A 2K render simply doesn't have enough pixels for antialiasing such a narrow and contrasty area.

[8K Render - High Contrast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQiE9.jpg) (still a little bit jagged)
[8K Render - Low Contrast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAact.jpg) (perfectly crisp edges)

[image]
[image]